# Why was this done to Lynn?

Tags: plot-explanation, hotel-beau-sejour

In [*Hotel Beau Sejour*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3543082/), why was Lynn (the victim) drugged by her own sister and what was the purpose behind that - to get her sister's boyfriend's attention?

Comment: Some context here would be useful. Which episode are you referring to?

Comment: I believe it was to get Leon upset with Kato in the hopes he would leave her.